# Good packages to typeset doctor prescription pad

Tags: packages, paper-size

I want to typeset a prescription pad for a doctor using LaTeX. 
I want to be able to style the header with relevant information and a image for the "cross", also I would like to specify the page size.

Which are best packages to achieve this?

Comment: you can use [`geometry`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) for the page size, [`fancyhdr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) for the headers.

Comment: It would be useful if you could show an example.